# How do I delete ROWS based on some calculations on column value in EXCEL

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, row

Please help me in below scenario,

I have some data in excel and I want to delete rows based on ID and higher Timestamp( I want to keep only latest records for each ID).

[image: This is sample data]

For each ID I want to keep only the first row as my data is sorted in descending order and I want to delete all other rows for that particular ID. For Example,

ID = 6000001, I only want to keep first row which has timestamp **2019-12-19**  and 2nd row I want to delete. Same way only high timestamp row I want to keep for all ID's.

Much Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper column with formula:

```
=--NOT(AGGREGATE(14,4,(A2=$A$2:$A$13)*$C$2:$C$13,1)=C2)
```

Then, filter and delete all the ones in that row.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response, I am new to excel formulas, it would be helpful if you please explain me a bit as well so that I can apply the formula to my data set. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help.  When I apply the same formula I get the calculated value as '1' and I see no '0', Could you please explain a bit the working of this formula so that I can rectify the error by myself. 

Helper
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: This is because the date is entered as text in your table. Try this formula: =--NOT(AGGREGATE(14;4;(A2=$A$2:$A$13)*(($C$2:$C$13)*1);1)=(C2*1))